# How do I add elements to an ArrayList in a map?

Tags: java, collections

I create an ArrayList in a map using

```
Map <String, ArrayList<String>> firmMSAMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>() ;
```

How do I add elements to the ArrayList within this map? Please correct me if my delcaration is wrong. I am trying to have a Map which contains an ArrayList

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Do you have any more sample code to post? Have you read the API? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to create a temporary ArrayList like `List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>` and then do `firmMSAMap.put(Key, temp);`

Comment: And what exactly does prevent you from doing that?

Comment: Confusion about logic prevents me from doing that. Actually I have an Excel which contains the name of cities, counties and what MSA they belong to. I want to have a list of all cities and counties belonging to a particular MSA nad then put it in a Map having MSA to city/county mapping. I want to do this for all MSAs. I have some ideas about doing this but I am not really sure if my logic is correct.

Comment: Also, I wanted to know if could have something like `map.put(key, arraylist.add(Element))` in java. As my `ArrayList` is not named, I don't know how  am I able to accomplish this.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  That is because `ArrayList.add()` does not return an ArrayList.  You should really learn to read the documentation.  You can read about Maps [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and Lists [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the String `foo` to the ArrayList keyed by the String `baz`:

```
firmMSAMap.get("baz").add("foo");
```

The above code does the following:

1. It retrieves the ArrayList stored with the key `baz`
2. It adds a String to the ArrayList

**NOTE:** This assumes that the Map already contains a value for the ke `baz.

Otherwise you would have to create a new ArrayList like this:

```
firmMSAMap.put("baz", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Here's a better example that checks to see if a value is mapped first:

```
Map<String, List<String>> theMap = ...

if (theMap.containsKey("baz")) {
    theMap.get("baz").add("foo");
}
else {
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    tempList.add("foo");
    theMap.put("baz", tempList);
}
```

Comment: No, the value is ArrayList<String>, not String.  Sorry, didn't read correctly-  this assumes the ArrayList has already been created.

Comment: @SteveH. - Actually, YES.  The question is how do you add a String to the ArrayList.

Comment: @Steve, `firmMSAMap.get("baz")` does return `ArrayList<String>` in this case, so the answer is good

Comment: Until a new ArrayList is created, there won't be one to add a string to.  I don't think the OP knows that.

Comment: although it could return a null pointer if there is nothing in the map for "baz"

Comment: Just edited the answer to add some more thorough examples that check to see if the Map contains the key first...

Answer (score 1):

You need to `get` that ArrayList from map and `add` element to it like

```
firmMSAMap.get("your List key").add("new element of list");
```

But of course to be able to do it your map need to contain that "your List key"->ArrayList pair first, so you need to `put` it there before

```
firmMSAMap.put("your List key", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should defined new ArrayList object and put it with key

Answer (score -1):

This maps String keys to ArrayList values.  So if you want an ArrayList at key "foo", then:

```
firmMSAMap.put("foo", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: The OP wants to know how to add elements to the `ArrayList`s contained in the map.